# iframe content not loaded while testing in Angular / Karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, iframe, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm implementing a navbar component in Angular from the App1 in another app called mainApp using . I wanted to do unit tests on the HomeComponent of mainApp which integrate the navigation module as shows the following code

```
 <iframe class="ext-navigation" src="http://localhost:4200/" title="navigation" loading="eager"></iframe>
```

On the browser everything works fine and the navigation appears without any problem, but while testing I couldn't get the content of the Navigation in the test logs and it shows empty content for the iframe

This is my test code:

```
  it('should contain the navigation links', async() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();  
    await fixture.whenStable();
    fixture.whenStable().then(()=>{
       fixture.detectChanges();  
       console.log(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.ext-navigation '));
    })
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    console.log(compiled.querySelector('.ext-navigation body'));
 
   expect(compiled.querySelector('app-navigation').textContent).toContain('home');
 });
```

Does anyone know how to wait for the iframe content to load in order to be able to test it in the spec.ts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I succeeded in solving that by

```
 <iframe class="ext-navigation" [src]="url" title="navigation" loading="eager" (load)="iframeSrc && iframeLoaded()"></iframe>
```

and added this Subject in the component ts file to wait for loading the content

```
public iframesLoaded: Subject<void> = new Subject();

public iframeLoaded(index: number) {
    this.iframesLoaded.next();
  }
```

and for my test case, I set the iframeSrc value to be truthy and the subscribed the Subject to get the final value:

```
  it('should display the navigation menu ["Home", "Contact", "About"]', (done) => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavbarComponent);
    let component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.iframeSrc = '/iframe';
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.iframesLoaded.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(val => {
      fixture.detectChanges();

      let navLinks = Array.from(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.ext-navigation').contentDocument.querySelectorAll('body ul a')).map((item: Node) => item.textContent)
      expect(navLinks).toContain("Home")
      expect(navLinks).toContain("Contact")
      expect(navLinks).toContain("About")

      done();
    });
  });
```